# fncychap.sty not found

Tags: errors, packages

These are the packages I used while during compilation I got this error see in the attachement.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\circledS\undefined 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\begin{document}
University
\end{document}
```

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @ Egreg: Sorry to ask this question. How can I look for it?

Comment: I see it's some flavor of TeX Live on a GNU/Linux distribution. Which one?

Comment: Linux distribution

Comment: There are umpteen Linux distributions: Ubuntu, Fedora, ArchLinux, whatnot.

Comment: Ok Ubuntu i am uisng.

Comment: LSB Version: :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
Release: 7.6.1810
Codename: Core

Comment: Use your package manager to install `texlive-latex-extra`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91979/discussion-between-higgs-and-egreg).

Answer (score 2):

For me the best answer was [@egreg's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483009/fncychap-sty-not-found#comment1221062_483009), install what ever your OS calls the package that installs TeX Live LaTeX extras:

- Debian/Ubuntu: `texlive-latex-extra`
- Alpine: `texlive-full`

Comment: Also Debian/Ubuntu 'texlive-latex-recommended' in some cases.  You can use `apt-file search fncychap.sty`.  I tried the tlmgr route, but it was returning error codes.

Answer (score 0):

If TeX Live installed with system package manager like APT, YUM or DNF, read the system manual for search required package.

If TeX Live installed with [installation shell script](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), use `tlmgr` utilite for install required TeX Live packages:

1. Initiate:

   ```bash
   tlmgr init-usertree
   ```
2. Add CTAN repository:

   ```bash
   tlmgr option repository ctan
   ```
3. Set repository URI:

   ```bash
   tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
   ```
4. Install required package:

   ```bash
   tlmgr install fncychap
   ```

Source: https://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html